# quiero hacer una consulta a una bd mysql, pero me arroja una pantalla en blanco al darle buscar

Tags: php, html

la conexión a la base de datos esta bien ya que no me arroja ningún error.

todo paso al migrar el sitio web a otro dominio; y dentro hay un proceso de consultar unos certificados, pero al momento de consultarlos solo me muestra una pantalla en blanco, no arroja ningún error tampoco.

no encuentro dónde esta el error y tampoco logro tener resultados en la búsqueda de la pagina.
el archivo contiene php y html

```
<?php require_once('Connections/acor.php'); 
?>

<?php mysqli_set_charset('utf8');?>
<?php 
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string") ? mysqli_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysqli_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}


$colname_certificados = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
  $colname_certificados = $_GET['search'];
}

mysqli_select_db($database_acor, $acor);
$query_certificados = sprintf("SELECT * FROM certificados WHERE Buscador LIKE %s ORDER BY CODIGO ASC", GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_certificados . "%", "text"));
$certificados = mysqli_query($query_certificados, $acor) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_certificados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($certificados);
$totalRows_certificados = mysqli_num_rows($certificados);

$buscar=$colname_certificados;
```

Por aqui el output

```
<?php do { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row_certificados['CODIGO']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_certificados['FECHA']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_certificados['EMPRESA']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_certificados['NIT']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_certificados['CANTIDAD']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_certificados['PESO']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_certificados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($certificados)); ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <?php } // Show if recordset not empty ?>
```

Comment: tu código tiene severos problemas ... tienes muchas etiquetas de apertura y cierre de php sin sentido, si el archivo contiene puramente php no necesitas mas que abrir la etiqueta una sola vez.

Comment: adicional no se ve en el código el output de la ejecución no hay ningún `echo`

Comment: Una página en blanco, en una configuración de producción, significa que se produjo un error fatal en el código. Deberías consultar el log de error de tu servidor Apache. Allí tendrás la información del error que has sufrido.